# ClassNotFoundException while running jar

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, unix, jar

I am getting `ClassNotFoundException` when I try to run a jar whith below command:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

I created the jar with eclipe. **MyJar** depends of a couple of other jars. I saw in ecplise that all these other jars are there in the **classpath**.

I also added these jars to the classpath in *Unix* using export classpath. But still I get the ClassNotFoundException.

**Exception Stack Trace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
    at com.a.HDFSCopy.readURI(HDFSCopy.java:16)
    at com.a.CopyMain.main(CopyMain.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
        ... 2 more
```

**Class Path Before:**

/opt/ibm/biginsights/IHC/lib/biginsights-gpfs-1.1.1.jar:/opt/ibm/biginsights/IHC/hadoop-core.jar:

**Class Path After (included the locations of the jars needed for dependencies) :**

> [biadmin@big-instght-15 ~]$ echo $CLASSPATH
>   /opt/ibm/biginsights/IHC/lib/biginsights-gpfs-1.1.1.jar:/opt/ibm/biginsights/IHC/hadoop-core.jar::/home/biadmin/hadoop_jars/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/biadmin/hadoop_jars/commons-configuration-1.8.jar:/home/biadmin/hadoop_jars/commons-lang-2.4.jar

But, I realized that if I open a new terminal and echo $CLASSPATH, it displays only the Class Path Before. It doesn't reflect the changes I made to the classpath. i.e. it doesn't show Class Path After.

How to fix this?

Thanks,

Mahalakshmi

Comment: show the complete stack trace here. we should know the class name for which it throwing the exception. If it is the class where main method is declared then you should check the class modifier is it public?

Comment: Which class is not found?

Comment: You need to post your application dependency tree along with the main entry.

Comment: Are you running the java command from the same terminal/shell in which you exported the classpath ? In other words - can you make sure that the classpath you exported is visible to the java command. Also - which class is not being found by java ? is it the main class or one of the dependencies ?

Comment: @Sumit: I have pasted the complete Stack Trace

Comment: @Jens: The class not found is: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

Comment: @Bhaskar: I am running the java command from the same terminal in which I exported the classpath. How to make sure if the exported classpath is visible to the java command? It is the dependency class which is not found by java

Comment: @MahalakshmiLakshminarayanan Can you please format the stacktrace as code. Itis readlly hard to read it.Thx

Comment: looks like [`hadoop-core.jar`](http://www.findjar.com/class/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html;jsessionid=2A2538E58F0BD910ECC7045FB1017E50) is missing in your classpath

Comment: hmmm.. but is present is in the classpath before I even made any changes to the classpath. Classpath(before: )/opt/ibm/biginsights/IHC/lib/biginsights-gpfs-1.1.1.jar:/opt/ibm/biginsights/IHC/hadoop-core.jar: I also exported other dependencies to the classpath after that.

Comment: Which Version of hadoop-core.jar you have?

Comment: How do I check the version of the hadoop-core.jar in the class path? I developed the program using hadoop-1.0.3.jar. I even added this jar to the class path. But still I get this exception

Comment: I also realized that when I opened a new terminal, I see echo $CLASSPATH does not reflect the changes that I made to the classpath.

Comment: @MahalakshmiLakshminarayanan , did you try the "java -cp <classpath>" command option where you can specify the classpath directly ?

Comment: When you open a new terminal , you dont see your full classpath because when you set it in one terminal - you are setting it for that shell ( and you are not admin I suppose )

Comment: @Bhaskar -cp doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

What is the main class listed in `MANIFEST.MF`?  If you unjar the jar, is it in the jarfile in the correct location?

Comment: The main class listed in the MANIFEST.MF is com.a.CopyMain This is the correct mmain class

Comment: MANIFEST.MF lists the main class correctly. However, it doesn't have information about the dependent classes